# Bazel Make variable substitution for the package root?

Tags: bazel

Suppose I have a Bazel project like this:

```sh
tree .
.
├── foo
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   └── foo.txt
└── WORKSPACE

1 directory, 3 files
```

`foo/BUILD.bazel`:

```py
genrule(
  name = "bar",
  srcs = [
    "foo.txt",
  ],
  cmd = "cp foo.txt $@",
  outs = [
    "bar.txt",
  ],
)
```

I cannot build `bazel build //foo:bar`:

```sh
bazel build //foo:bar

...

cp: cannot stat 'foo.txt': No such file or directory
```

It appears that paths in `cmd` must be relative to the `WORKSPACE` root, rather than the `BUILD` root.

This works:

```py
genrule(
  name = "bar",
  srcs = [
    "foo.txt",
  ],
  # cmd = "cp foo.txt $@",
  cmd = "cp foo/foo.txt $@",
  outs = [
    "bar.txt",
  ],
)
```

It's inconvenient to have to specify the full path, particularly when `BUILD` files might be moved around.

It is also nice to be able to write scripts *as if* they run from their location in the source-tree (of course they are *actually* run in the sandbox!)

Is there a Make variable substitution that would allow me to specify this more cleanly?

For example:

```py
genrule(
  name = "bar",
  srcs = [
    "foo.txt",
  ],
  cmd = "cd $(SRCDIR) && cp foo.txt $@",
  outs = [
    "bar.txt",
  ],
)
```

Here `$(SRCDIR)` could expand to `./foo`.

Note that this is a contrived example. I cannot use `$(SRCS)` since I need to use the input files in different ways. I also cannot use `$<` since I have more than once `srcs`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are such Make variables. In this particular case `$<` is the most convenient, so the rule declaration will look like this:

```py
    genrule(
      name = "bar",
      srcs = ["foo.txt"],
      outs = ["bar.txt"],
      cmd = "cp $< $@",
    )
```

`$<` can be used if there is only one file in srcs. If there are more of them, then consider using `$(SRCS)` which will expand in space-separated inputs from srcs.

Also, there are predefined path substitutions, such as `$(execpath)` and `$(rootpath)` which expand labels to their full paths. So, the snippet mentioned above will look similar to this:

```py
    genrule(
      name = "bar",
      srcs = ["foo.txt"],
      outs = ["bar.txt"],
      cmd = "cp $(execpath foo.txt) $@",
    )
```

And there is `$(location)` expansion which is synonym for either `execpath` or `rootpath` (depending on the context) but it's legacy and using it is not recommended.

Here you can check the official docs on Make variables in Bazel: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/be/make-variables.html

Comment: I cannot use `$(SRCS)` since I need to use the input files in different ways. Sorry should have made that more clear.

Comment: "And there is $(location) expansion which is synonym for either execpath or rootpath (depending on the context) but it's legacy and using it is not recommended." - do you have a source for this information?

Comment: @Jin, it's all from [official docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/be/make-variables.html). That's what they say:

> `location`: A synonym for either `execpath` or `rootpath`, depending on the attribute being expanded. This is legacy pre-Starlark behaviour and not recommended unless you really know what it does for a particular rule. See [#2475](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2475#issuecomment-339318016) for details.

Comment: Is there not a macro for the path to the `BUILD` file? This would enable me to `cd` to the correct place then run the script unchanged. This is much more convenient when porting this to Bazel.

Comment: I don't think there is such macro but I guess you can use smth like this to extract dir from path:
```$$(dirname $(SRCS)[0])```

Comment: The problem with that is the sources can be in different locations. The main difference is source files (like `foo.txt`) vs outputs from other rules (imagine another rule using `bar.txt` as an input). Those live in separate trees, so `//foo:a.txt` and `//foo:b.txt` might live in different folders. Might not apply to your situation now, but bazel is designed to support that so there's nothing builtin to get your path.